# Does a React component deeply compare props to check if rerender is needed?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I would like to know if a React component extending `React.Component` deeply compares an object when trying to decide if it needs to rerender.

For instance, given

```
const Foo = ({ bar }) => {
  return <div>{bar.baz}</div>
}

class App extends React.Component {
  constructor() {
    super()
    this.state = { bar: { baz: 1} }
  }

  render() {
    return <Foo bar={this.state.bar} />
  }
}
```

If inside `App`, the state `bar` changes to `{baz: 2}`, does `<Foo />` deeply compare the previous prop `bar` and the newly received prop?

Incidentally, [the docs for PureComponent](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-api.html#reactpurecomponent) says

> Extend PureComponent ... Or, consider using immutable objects to facilitate fast comparisons of nested data.

But does not go into much more details. Any ideas?

Comment: Yes it does unless it is pure component or you are using some lifecycle like shouldcomponentupdate.

Comment: Can you provide all relevant code? How exactly does `baz` change? Do you just assign it without `setState`?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Unless you implement a `shouldComponentUpdate` lifecycle method yourself, a component extending **`React.Component`** won't compare the props before going through a re-render cycle where it compares the previous and current Virtual DOM to decide what to re-render

Also a component extended using **`React.PureComponent`** doesn't deeply compare props with prevProps and state with prevState but performs shallow comparison to decide, if at all a re-render is needed or not.

For a **`Functional component`** from **v16.6.0** onwards, React has introduced a Higher Order Function, `React.memo` which can be used to make a functional component behave as a `React.PureComponent`

According to the **[docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-api.html#reactmemo)**:

> `React.memo` is a higher order component. It’s similar to
>   `React.PureComponent` but for function components instead of classes.
>
> It can be used like
>
> ```
> const MyComponent = React.memo(function MyComponent(props) {
>   /* render using props */
> });
> ```
>
> If your function component renders the same result given the same
>   props, you can wrap it in a call to React.memo for a performance boost
>   in some cases by memoizing the result. This means that React will skip
>   rendering the component, and reuse the last rendered result.
>
> By default it will only `shallowly compare complex objects` in the props
>   object. If you want control over the comparison, you can also provide
>   a custom comparison function as the second argument.

Comment: How exactly does this help?

Comment: @estus, what exactly are you talking about?

Comment: That's a good piece of information, I didn't notice `React.memo` in 16.6, but the second part of the answer seems to not be linked to the question.

Comment: @estus, the second part is not a direct answer to the question but provides more information regarding use of PureComponent for functional components.

Comment: Thanks. So if an instance of `React.Component` does not implement `shouldComponentUpdate`, does it always call `render` and update the DOM if necessary?

Comment: @SungWonCho, yes, an instance of React.Component will always render

Comment: This is a very important key that I am not sure if all understand because this key phrase *shallowly compare complex objects* decides if a component re-renders or not when you are sending a prop that is a bit more complex and this can cause problems if you don't know about this.

Answer (score 6):

'Extend PureComponent' was quoted out of context. The documentation says the opposite,

> Only extend PureComponent when you expect to have simple props and state

Because

> React.PureComponent’s shouldComponentUpdate() only shallowly compares the objects. If these contain complex data structures, it may produce false-negatives for deeper differences.

React components don't compare props, unless they implement `shouldComponentUpdate`, like `PureComponent`. A component can be re-rendered with exactly same prop (`===` equal).

If the state is mutated but isn't forced to update (this is an antipattern), children won't be re-rendered.

If the state is mutated and forced to update (this is an antipattern), children are re-rendered:

```
class App extends React.Component {
  componentDidMount() {
     this.state.bar.baz = 2;
     this.setState(state);
  }
  ...    
}
```

In order to limit updates to deeply changed props, `Foo` should implement `shouldComponentUpdate` with deep comparison, e.g. Lodash `isEqual`:

```
class Foo extends React.Component {
  shouldComponentUpdate(nextProps, nextState) {
    return !_.isEqual(this.props, nextProps) || this.state !== nextState;
  }
  ...
}
```

Since deep comparison may be costly, performance tests should be run to determine whether it provides performance improvements.

Immutable state and props are highly welcome in React because they allow to avoid this problem. If an object changes in some way, it should be replaced with another object, i.e. state update should result in new `state` and `state.bar` objects:

```
class App extends React.Component {
  componentDidMount() {
    this.setState(({ bar })=> ({
      bar: { ...bar, baz: 2 }
    });
  }
  ...    
}
```

In this case `Foo` needs to shallowly compare `bar` object it receives as a prop, so it can be `PureComponent`, or `React.memo` (as another answer explains).