# Is there a nested limit to react's change detection

Tags: reactjs

I'm passing a complicated object with a lot of nested props. I have a a component that uses a deeply nested prop as

```
props.one.two[nth].three[nth].four = boolean
```

and a change in this boolean does not trigger a rerender in the component using it. I can see the bool update correctly in the dev tools and in logs, but render is not called until i perform some other action on this component (like typing) and then it rerenders to show the boolean update.

i just want to know if react's change detection has some kind of limit on how deeply nested it will detect.

Comment: How are you changing the value of the prop, are you changing it in a parent component?

Comment: yeah way up the tree. we're drilling; not using any state mgt

Comment: It should rerender unless it is pure component (or React.memo) or you are using some lifecycle like `shouldComponentUpdate`

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52982725/does-a-react-component-deeply-compare-props-to-check-if-rerender-is-needed

Comment: !!! @JBaczuk you found it! In a component in the middle of the tree, someone had changed React.Component to React.PureComponent. I checked them after reading the SO post you linked above. Wow you did it. if you want points, post an answer below and I'll approve it. Thanks so much!

Comment: awesome glad you found it!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the docs, the component will do a deep check on objects in order to determine if a rerender is required, unless that component is a [React.PureComponent](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-api.html#reactpurecomponent) (for class compomnents) or uses [React.memo](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-api.html#reactmemo) (for function components), which will only do a shallow compare.

It might also not rerender if you are implementing [`shouldComponentUpdate`](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#shouldcomponentupdate) and it returns false.